# WSO2 Where are the Claims stored?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I thought the claims should be stored in UM_CLAIM in the user store but mine is empty, however when I enable JWT in the header I'm getting X-JWT-Assertion populated with values. I've also checked IDP_CLAIM in the AM db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified what is the version of WSO2 API Manager that you are using, I am answering this question targeting API Manager latested released version 2.1.0.

For WSO2 API Manager the claim related tables are below.

IDN_CLAIM
 IDN_CLAIM_DIALECT
 IDN_CLAIM_MAPPED_ATTRIBUTE
 IDN_CLAIM_MAPPING
 IDN_CLAIM_PROPERTY

And you should be able to see data related to claims stored in this tables if you can successfully get the X-JWT-Assertion when invoking the API.
[image]

Check whether you have uncommented all the default values as denoted in the **Configuring JWT** section of the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT#PassingEnduserAttributestotheBackendUsingJWT-ConfiguringJWT).